# GCM did not unregister the device when the app is uninstalled

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I made an Android app. I used **GCM** to push notifications. I am registering the device with GCM when the user 
is logged in.   I am using **external MySql database** to store the
registration ids of  users. It worked fine.

But

When I did the following steps :

1. **Installed** my app in my mobile.
2. Logged in  with **user1**.
3. **Uninstalled** the app from my mobile.
4. **Installed** the app again.
5. Logged in with **user2**.

**user1** notifications are still received in my mobile it means GCM **did not** unregister my device when app is uninstalled.

I can not delete the row in Mysql database when the app is uninstalled, because I will not know when the app is uninstalled or user may not have internet
connection at the time of  uninstalling the app to delete row.

Can you please suggest me how to solve this problem?

I read that GCM will take some time to unregister the device after uninstall.

How can I delete row in mysql when GCM unregistered the device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true that GCM will take some time to unregister the device after uninstalling. Based on the [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#how-uninstalled-client-app-unregistration-works), the GCM server will mark the registration ID for deletion only after sending a message that "bounces back" because the app has been uninstalled.

If only to make the situation a bit more complicated, the re-installed app can receive the same registration ID or a different one.

One thing you can do is add a field in your `data` JSON object to specify who the intended user is. That way, regardless of the scenario where the app has been uninstalled and then re-installed, the user will only receive messages that were intended for them (for example, by making some sort of "check logged in user" function).

Additional notes from the documentation:

> To make sure that messages go to the intended user:
>
> - The app server can maintain a mapping between the current user and the registration token.
> - The client app can then check to ensure that messages it receives match the logged in user.